# Child image's width doesn't modify its parent width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, width, microsoft-edge

I have an image nested inside a series of `<div>` tags. I have the image in `height: 100%;` and `width: auto;`. When I resize the height of my browser, the image changes its size but somehow the parent div doesn't change in IE and Edge (fine for all other browsers).

Here is the normal render on chrome when you resize your browser:

[image: Here is the normal render on chrome when you resize your browser]

Here is the problem in IE when you resize:

[image: Here is the problem in IE when you resize]

Or like this:

[image: Or like this]

I'm trying to resize the parent in relation with the image's width. The parent container just doesn't resize. Here is my `<div>` structure:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
}

#photo-gallery {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.project {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  border: solid 18px #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="photo-gallery">
  <div class="project">
    <img src="img/landscape1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is my CodePen (open in IE or Edge)](https://codepen.io/quentinver/pen/YvMNZx)

Right now I got it working with JavaScript by detecting the width of the image and giving it to the immediate parent, but that's really far from ideal... am I missing something? The strange thing is, if you resize your window and then reload the page, the image shows with the right size/proportions until you resize the browser again.

Comment: try to use `min-height` no `height`

Comment: You mean like `min-height: 0;` ? I just tried but it didn't change anything